# rm wildcard is not working on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have the following directory listing:

```
  0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Sep  2 15:19 aws.greengrass.LambdaLauncher.log
  0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Sep  2 15:19 aws.greengrass.LambdaRuntimes.log
  0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Sep  2 14:53 aws.greengrass.Nucleus.log
 80 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  75017 Sep  2 15:55 greengrass_2022_09_02_15_0.log
 40 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36930 Sep  2 16:50 greengrass_2022_09_02_16_0.log
216 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 217065 Sep  2 20:40 greengrass_2022_09_02_20_0.log
 96 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  92764 Sep  2 21:54 greengrass_2022_09_02_21_0.log
 64 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58307 Sep  2 22:57 greengrass_2022_09_02_22_0.log
 48 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  46475 Sep  6 14:37 greengrass_2022_09_06_14_0.log
 16 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14845 Sep  6 17:57 greengrass_2022_09_06_17_0.log
 40 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39037 Sep  6 18:11 greengrass_2022_09_06_18_0.log
184 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 186318 Sep  6 19:48 greengrass_2022_09_06_19_0.log
 12 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10793 Sep  6 20:25 greengrass_2022_09_06_20_0.log
124 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 122363 Sep  6 21:43 greengrass.log
```

I want to delete any file who's name starts with greengrass. I have tried these wildcard commands but none of them work:

```
sudo rm /greengrass/v2/logs/greengrass*.*
sudo rm /greengrass/v2/logs/greengrass*
sudo rm /greengrass/v2/logs/greengrass*.log
```

I get:

```
rm: cannot remove '/greengrass/v2/logs/greengrass*.*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: what does `ls -al /greengrass/v2/logs/` show?

Comment: Related - [Why isn't this sudo mv operation with wildcard working?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309255/100397)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is all about glob expansion.

when you run:

```
 sudo rm dir/*
```

the shell running the sudo tries to expand the '*' wildcard.  If it cannot read the directory, then it passes the wildcard to sudo as is.

sudo executes `rm` with `dir/*` and rm does not do glob expansion, only shells do.  rm is looking for a file called `*` which is a legal (but unusual) filename.

If the directory was readable by the user running sudo, then the acutall sudo command would be:

```
sudo rm dir/filea dir/fileb dir/filec
```

which would have worked.  since you want root to do the glob expansion you will need to use a shell as follows

```
sudo sh -c "rm dir/*"
```

Then sudo will run a shell as root, that will run the command "rm dir/*"  since shell understand how to expand globs, then it will be turned into "rm dir/filea dir/fileb ..."

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory /greengrass/v2/logs readable by your regular user? If not, it'll do this because the wildcard needs to be expanded to a list of matching files by the shell (before it's passed to `sudo`, which passes it on to `rm`), and if the shell can't list the contents of the directory... that doesn't happen.

The easiest solution is probably to use `sudo -s` to open a root shell, then run `rm /greengrass/v2/logs/greengrass*.*` from that root shell. And then use either `exit` or Control-D to exit the root shell and go back to normal.